# Cannot build boost python library (fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory)

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, boost, boost-python

I am trying to build the boost python library on my ubuntu. However, when I execute

```
./b2 --with-python
```

It always returns me errors related to

```
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:57:11: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 # include <pyconfig.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to look up online, e.g., https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/289

Follow their suggestion I check my "project-config.jam"
And I found

```
# Python configuration
import python ;
if ! [ python.configured ]
{
    using python : 3.7 : /home/lowlimb/anaconda3 :/home/lowlimb/anaconda3/include/python3.7m;
}
```

Which is correct, thus I really don't know how to fix this issue.
Can anyone provide me some advice?

Answer (score 5):

`pyconfig.h` is installed with `sudo apt install python-dev`

To build with a specific python version, you can do

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=<path to python>
```

e.g.

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3
```

to use your system's python3 or

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python
```

to use the python from your virtual environment.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to installing the python dev libs as suggested by the other answers, you can specify the python path directly:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.7 make
```

Or in your case something like:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/lowlimb/anaconda3/include/python3.7 ./b2
```

This worked for me when compiling a projects using Boost Python where I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to build Boost-Python or more generally, use Python from C/C++, you need the [Python development files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3.7-dev):

```
$ sudo apt install python3.7-dev
```

Comment: Do I have to do anything to project-config.jam? It is still using anaconda's python.