# pyconfig.h: No such file or directory while trying to use boost for cpp/python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to get access to a c++ class inside a python script - I want to import the class and use it in the python file as part a module.
I've installed boost library on ubuntu - it is saved at `/usr/include/` folder.
In addition I have `python2.7` and `python3.8` folders in the `/usr/include/` folder.
and Inside each of those folders I found the `pyconfig.h` file.

I'm having trouble compiling my code and getting this error message: `pyconfig.h: No such file or directory`

I've looked at these posts and I couldn't solve it:

[Cannot build boost python library (fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244655/cannot-build-boost-python-library-fatal-error-pyconfig-h-no-such-file-or-dire)

[hello world python extension in c++ using boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007185/hello-world-python-extension-in-c-using-boost)

[Failing to install Boost in Python - pyconfig.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839382/failing-to-install-boost-in-python-pyconfig-h-not-found)

The error pops up on this line: `include <boost/python.hpp>`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: you need to add the right folder to your include path

Comment: @KennyOstrom can you explain it?

Comment: See the third link in your question. It's something you configure in your makefile, IDE or command line. e.g. Look at the gcc command line option -Ipath